# in Vue3 is composition api the same as option api when it comes to testing?

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs3, vitest

I have a project that needs  testing and it is created using the composition api, however,  I am not sure if testing works the same for both api.

I  have googled to find some information but not luck so far, any recommendation will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing at component level they are pretty similar from the testing standpoint.

Composition API, however, makes it easier to move functionality outside of the component and write unit tests.

Comment: thanks @daniel , you just confirmed what I thought